# The shortcut of while loops

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can some one give me shortcut for this code?

```
list1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['h'',i','j']]
a = []
i = 0
while i < 4 :
  a.append(list1[0])
  i += 1
i = 0
while i < 4:
  a.append(list1[1])
  i += 1 
i = 0
while i < 4:
  a.append(list1[2])
  i += 1
```

print(a)

I want my output should be:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h', 'i', 'j'], ['h', 'i', 'j'], ['h', 'i', 'j'], ['h', 'i', 'j']]
```

Comment: And did you mean to append *references* or *copies* of the nested lists? `a[0][0] = 'spam'` will be reflected across `a[1]`, `a[2]` and `a[3]` as well.

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension would do this for you:

```
a = [sublist for sublist in list1 for i in range(4)]
```

Note that this only creates *additional references* to the lists contained in `list1`, not copies.

Demo:

```
>>> list1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h,i', 'j']]
>>> a = [sublist for sublist in list1 for i in range(4)]
>>> a
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h,i', 'j'], ['h,i', 'j'], ['h,i', 'j'], ['h,i', 'j']]
>>> a[0][0] = 'spam'
>>> a
[['spam', 'b', 'c'], ['spam', 'b', 'c'], ['spam', 'b', 'c'], ['spam', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h,i', 'j'], ['h,i', 'j'], ['h,i', 'j'], ['h,i', 'j']]
```

Note how a change to the first nested list is reflected across the first *four* lists? That's because those are all the same object. If you wanted to create *copies*, use the `list()` function, or the `[:]` identity slice operator:

```
a = [sublist[:] for sublist in list1 for i in range(4)]
```